# Service property is not accessible in component.html

Tags: angular, angular7, angular7-router

My intention is to create print module as detailed in this [article](https://medium.com/@Idan_Co/angular-print-service-290651c721f9). 
I am getting following error while loading my app.component.html:

```
AppComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'isPrinting' of undefined
```

**App.component.html**

```
<div [class.isPrinting]= "printService.isPrinting">
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <h1>
      Welcome to {{title}}!
    </h1>
     <button (click) ="onPrintReport()"> Print Report</button>     
     <router-outlet name='print"'></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

**App.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {PrintService} from './print.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'printer';
  constructor(public printServive: PrintService) {
    //console.log("Print:", this.printServive.isPrinting);
  }  
}
```

**print.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PrintService{
    isPrinting = false;

    constructor(private router: Router) {}   
}
```

**Style.css**

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@media print {
    .isPrinting > * { display: none; }
    .isPrinting app-print-layout { display: block; }
  }
```

Could you please let me know what change I have to make it work?

Comment: small typo, close your question

Comment: @Sajeetharan Thank you for the recommendation. Got an answer from Dennis, I don't feel fair to reject his effort. Do you mind if I keep the question?

Comment: i guess it will be closed anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You named your service `printServive` instead of `printService`. So the service can't be found so calling a property on that undefined property causes this error.